# xmlstarlet: output ends after the first match, but there are more and I need them all

Tags: xml, syntax, xmlstarlet

I get measurement data as an xml file like in the shortened example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RMCU>
    <TP id="Geb-T-TR">
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T18:30:03Z</DATETIME><TMP>21.323</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T18:45:03Z</DATETIME><TMP>21.078</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T19:00:03Z</DATETIME><TMP>22.423</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
    </TP>
    <TP id="ST-T_RL-FW">
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T18:30:01Z</DATETIME><TMP>65.800</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T18:45:00Z</DATETIME><TMP>58.900</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
        <VALUES><DATETIME>2021-11-27T19:00:00Z</DATETIME><TMP>60.900</TMP><STATUS>0</STATUS></VALUES>
    </TP>
</RMCU>
```

using the command line

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /RMCU/TP -v "concat(VALUES/DATETIME,';',@id,';',VALUES/TMP)" -n short.xml
```

I only get

```
2021-11-27T18:30:03Z;Geb-T-TR;21.323
2021-11-27T18:30:01Z;ST-T_RL-FW;65.800
```

But I need all measurement data:

```
2021-11-27T18:30:03Z;Geb-T-TR;21.3230
2021-11-27T18:45:03Z;Geb-T-TR;21.0780
2021-11-27T19:00:03Z;Geb-T-TR;22.4230
2021-11-27T18:30:01Z;ST-T_RL-FW;65.8000
2021-11-27T18:45:00Z;ST-T_RL-FW;58.9000
2021-11-27T19:00:00Z;ST-T_RL-FW;60.9000
```

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to apply the `for-each` to the `VALUES` nodes, e.g.:

```
xml sel -T -t -m /RMCU/TP/VALUES -v 'concat(DATETIME, ";", parent::TP/@id, ";", TMP)' -n
```

Output:

```
2021-11-27T18:30:03Z;Geb-T-TR;21.323
2021-11-27T18:45:03Z;Geb-T-TR;21.078
2021-11-27T19:00:03Z;Geb-T-TR;22.423
2021-11-27T18:30:01Z;ST-T_RL-FW;65.800
2021-11-27T18:45:00Z;ST-T_RL-FW;58.900
2021-11-27T19:00:00Z;ST-T_RL-FW;60.900
```